# how to enumerate only blob names in azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need a fastest way to enumerate all blob names in container. Container contains about 600 thousand blobs. Now i enumerates it as follow:

```
while(true) {
...         
 var blobChank = azureClient.ListBlobs(null, true, BlobListingDetails.None, null, null).Skip(counter * chankSize).Take(chankSize).ToList();
 if(blobChank.Count == 0) break;
 counter++;
...
///retrieve blob names
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the BlobProperties to get the name:

```
var blobChank = ... ;
foreach (object o in blobChank)
{
    BlobProperties bp = o as BlobProperties;
    if (bp != null)
    {
        BlobProperties p = _Container.GetBlobProperties(bp.Name);
        var name = p.Name; // get the name
    }
}
```

or via Linq :

> List blobNames = blobChank .Select(b => (b as
>   CloudBlockBlob).Name);

and for speed of iteration , you can download the blobs locally , see here : http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/all-Blobs-with-Snapshots-3b184a79